# ffmpeg / mencoder converting a video with correct setting

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, transcoding, handbrake

I have an avi video file that plays on my Onn-W7 player [Link to avi video file that works](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nfpnso35rjefs55/ONN.avi)  and [backup link to avi file that works.](http://speedy.sh/A7rdf/ONN.avi) I'm trying to convert some other video files over so that they will also play on it.  I've tried handbrake, ffmpeg and mencoder but the video fails to work most likely do to the fact I have some settings wrong in the conversion process but I don't know which ones any ideas how to fix this

**Here's the settings of the avi file that works below:**

```
General
Complete name                            : /tmp/ONN.avi
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
File size                                : 11.0 MiB
Duration                                 : 3mn 1s
Overall bit rate                         : 508 Kbps
Writing application                      : MEncoder Sherpya-MinGW-20060312-4.1.0
Writing library                          : MPlayer

Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : MPEG-4 Visual
Format profile                           : Simple@L3
Format settings, BVOP                    : No
Format settings, QPel                    : No
Format settings, GMC                     : No warppoints
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default (H.263)
Codec ID                                 : XVID
Codec ID/Hint                            : XviD
Duration                                 : 3mn 1s
Bit rate                                 : 371 Kbps
Width                                    : 160 pixels
Height                                   : 128 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 5:3
Original display aspect ratio            : 5:4
Frame rate                               : 15.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 1.207
Stream size                              : 8.00 MiB (73%)
Writing library                          : XviD 1.1.0 (UTC 2005-11-22)

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 2
Codec ID                                 : 50
Duration                                 : 3mn 1s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 2.77 MiB (25%)
Alignment                                : Split accross interleaves
Interleave, duration                     : 26 ms (0.39 video frame)
Interleave, preload duration             : 522 ms
```

**The ffmpeg command I tried is:**

```
ffmpeg -i "video_to_convert.mp4" -c:v libxvid -vf scale=160x128,setsar=1 -b:v 800k -r 15 -c:a libtwolame -ac 2 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -y video_converted.avi
```

**Here's the requested info of the command above on a file that doesn't work:**

```
mediainfo --fullscan video_converted.avi
General
Count                                    : 322
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : General
Kind of stream                           : General
Stream identifier                        : 0
Count of video streams                   : 1
Count of audio streams                   : 1
Video_Format_List                        : xvid
Video_Format_WithHint_List               : xvid
Codecs Video                             : xvid
Audio_Format_List                        : MPEG Audio
Audio_Format_WithHint_List               : MPEG Audio
Audio codecs                             : MPEG-1 Audio layer 2
Complete name                            : video_converted.avi
File name                                : video_converted
File extension                           : avi
Format                                   : AVI
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
Format/Extensions usually used           : avi
Commercial name                          : AVI
Internet media type                      : video/vnd.avi
Interleaved                              : Yes
Codec                                    : AVI
Codec                                    : AVI
Codec/Info                               : Audio Video Interleave
Codec/Extensions usually used            : avi
File size                                : 4297704
File size                                : 4.10 MiB
File size                                : 4 MiB
File size                                : 4.1 MiB
File size                                : 4.10 MiB
File size                                : 4.099 MiB
Duration                                 : 165267
Duration                                 : 2mn 45s
Duration                                 : 2mn 45s 267ms
Duration                                 : 2mn 45s
Duration                                 : 00:02:45.267
Duration                                 : 00:02:45:04
Duration                                 : 00:02:45.267 (00:02:45:04)
Overall bit rate                         : 208037
Overall bit rate                         : 208 Kbps
Frame rate                               : 15.000
Frame rate                               : 15.000 fps
Frame count                              : 2479
Stream size                              : 228958
Stream size                              : 224 KiB (5%)
Stream size                              : 224 KiB
Stream size                              : 224 KiB
Stream size                              : 224 KiB
Stream size                              : 223.6 KiB
Stream size                              : 224 KiB (5%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.05327
File last modification date              : UTC 2016-09-16 10:15:46
File last modification date (local)      : 2016-09-16 06:15:46
Writing application                      : Lavf56.40.101
Writing application                      : Lavf56.40.101

Video
Count                                    : 332
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : Video
Kind of stream                           : Video
Stream identifier                        : 0
ID                                       : 0
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : xvid
Commercial name                          : xvid
Codec ID                                 : xvid
Codec                                    : xvid
Codec                                    : xvid
Codec/CC                                 : xvid
Duration                                 : 165267
Duration                                 : 2mn 45s
Duration                                 : 2mn 45s 267ms
Duration                                 : 2mn 45s
Duration                                 : 00:02:45.267
Duration                                 : 00:02:45:04
Duration                                 : 00:02:45.267 (00:02:45:04)
Bit rate                                 : 69281
Bit rate                                 : 69.3 Kbps
Width                                    : 160
Width                                    : 160 pixels
Height                                   : 128
Height                                   : 128 pixels
Pixel aspect ratio                       : 1.000
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.250
Display aspect ratio                     : 5:4
Frame rate                               : 15.000
Frame rate                               : 15.000 fps
Frame count                              : 2479
Scan type                                : Progressive
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.226
Delay                                    : 0
Delay                                    : 00:00:00.000
Stream size                              : 1431221
Stream size                              : 1.36 MiB (33%)
Stream size                              : 1 MiB
Stream size                              : 1.4 MiB
Stream size                              : 1.36 MiB
Stream size                              : 1.365 MiB
Stream size                              : 1.36 MiB (33%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.33302

Audio
Count                                    : 272
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : Audio
Kind of stream                           : Audio
Stream identifier                        : 0
StreamOrder                              : 1
ID                                       : 1
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Commercial name                          : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 2
Internet media type                      : audio/mpeg
Codec ID                                 : 50
Codec ID/Url                             : http://www.iis.fraunhofer.de/amm/index.html
Codec                                    : MPA1L2
Codec                                    : MPEG-1 Audio layer 2
Codec/Family                             : MPEG-1
Codec/Url                                : http://www.iis.fraunhofer.de/amm/index.html
Codec/CC                                 : 50
Duration                                 : 165224
Duration                                 : 2mn 45s
Duration                                 : 2mn 45s 224ms
Duration                                 : 2mn 45s
Duration                                 : 00:02:45.224
Duration                                 : 00:02:45.224
Bit rate mode                            : CBR
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128000
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44100
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Samples count                            : 7286378
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay                                    : 0
Delay                                    : 00:00:00.000
Delay, origin                            : Stream
Delay, origin                            : Raw stream
Delay relative to video                  : 0
Delay relative to video                  : 00:00:00.000
Video0 delay                             : 0
Video0 delay                             : 00:00:00.000
Stream size                              : 2637525
Stream size                              : 2.52 MiB (61%)
Stream size                              : 3 MiB
Stream size                              : 2.5 MiB
Stream size                              : 2.52 MiB
Stream size                              : 2.515 MiB
Stream size                              : 2.52 MiB (61%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.61371
Alignment                                : Aligned
Alignment                                : Aligned on interleaves
Interleave, duration                     : 0.39
Interleave, duration                     : 26
Interleave, duration                     : 26 ms (0.39 video frame)
```

**Also without the fullscan option:**

```
mediainfo video_converted.avi
General
Complete name                            : video_converted.avi
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
File size                                : 4.10 MiB
Duration                                 : 2mn 45s
Overall bit rate                         : 208 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf56.40.101

Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : xvid
Codec ID                                 : xvid
Duration                                 : 2mn 45s
Bit rate                                 : 69.3 Kbps
Width                                    : 160 pixels
Height                                   : 128 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 5:4
Frame rate                               : 15.000 fps
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.226
Stream size                              : 1.36 MiB (33%)

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 2
Codec ID                                 : 50
Duration                                 : 2mn 45s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 2.52 MiB (61%)
Alignment                                : Aligned on interleaves
Interleave, duration                     : 26 ms (0.39 video frame)
```

The products website is
[Onn-w7 website](http://en.onnchina.com/mp3_mp4/product172.html)

Here's the little manual in Chinese which I can't read
[image: page 1]
[image: page 2]

Comment: Can you add the media info for a (nonworking) file encoded with the above command line?

Comment: @Eric I added the media info for a (nonworking) file encoded with the above command line?

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -i "video_to_convert.mp4" -c:v libxvid -vtag XVID -level 1 -vf scale=160x128,setsar=1 -b:v 800k -r 15 -c:a libtwolame -ac 2 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -y video_converted.avi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the player is using the video codec tag to vet files. And it is picky about case. So try

```
ffmpeg -i "video_to_convert.mp4" -c:v libxvid -vtag XVID -level 1
       -vf scale=160x128,setsar=1 -b:v 800k -r 15
       -c:a libtwolame -ac 2 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -y video_converted.avi
```

(The level may not be necessary. I was testing something.)